# how to show an image in an image field by a button click event in c# asp.net

Tags: c#

I have a problem to change imageUrl of an image field. i want to show the uploaded image by clicking a button named "upload".
here is my server side code:

```
if (fileUpload.HasFile)
{           Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo"));
            string targetFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo");
            string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, "photo.png");
            fileUpload.SaveAs(targetPath);
            employeeImage.ImageUrl = targetPath;
}
```

Comment: what's happening instead?

Comment: image is loaded. but did not show image. just stay blank.

Comment: have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599228/upload-image-rename-it-make-thumbnail-and-replace-the-original-optimization

Comment: i checked but don't understand. i don't want to make thumbnail. i want to sho original image.

Comment: try changing employeeImage.imageUrl to employeeImage.Source = targetPath

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by using webhandler(.ashx).

```
public class   ImageHandler:IHttpHandler,System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

{

  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    //Checking whether the imagebytes variable have anything else not doin anything
    if ((context.Session["ImageBytes"]) != null)
    {
        byte[] image = (byte[])(context.Session["ImageBytes"]);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(image);
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

and server side code is:

```
protected void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ImageBytes"] = fileUpload.FileBytes;
    employeeImage.ImageUrl = "~/ImageHandler.ashx";
}
```